# SharePoint 2013 Search results not as expected

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, enterprise-search

We have a SharePoint 2013 Site Collection (has been upgraded from 2010)

I setup a new search service on the new server and search is working well.  Enterprise Search.

However is a user searches for e.g. "Initial Entry" they are only getting results where the exact phrase is in the results.

However in our 2010 instance, the same search would also include results with "Initial" and results with "Entry" as separate words.

Have I missed a configuration option somewhere?  Or does 2013 search just work differently?

Answer (score 0):

Did you do a Full Crawl? for the Whole Farm? and did you include that site collection  to the Content being Crawlled

Comment: Make sure  you have done a ful crawl on the whole farm. on you server

Comment: Yes, have done a full crawl. and there is only one site collection being crawled.

Answer (score 0):

You will get results which includes the word Initial OR Entry  if you have given without double quotes.

I checked in my farm and it is working fine.

If you give within double-quotes "Initial Entry" you will get only results for Initial AND Entry .

Also please ensure that Full crawl happened and see the items it successfully crawl from Crawl Logs.

Refer Microsoft SharePoint KQL [Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee558911.aspx)